# Does Swift not work with function pointers?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, lua, swift

I'm trying to use a C library in Swift, and I'm having trouble calling any function that takes a function pointer as one of it's arguments. For example, part of the lua.h file that I'm trying to use in Swift looks like this:

```
LUA_API void  (lua_setuservalue) (lua_State *L, int idx);


typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L);

LUA_API void  (lua_callk) (lua_State *L, int nargs, int nresults, int ctx,
                       lua_CFunction k);
```

I use the bridging header to get access to the library, and from my Swift code I can call **lua_setuservalue** without any trouble. But if I try to call **lua_callk** I get "use of unresolved identifier 'lua_callk'". If I remove the function pointer from the declaration for **lua_callk**, I no longer get this error. Any help is quite appreciated.

Comment: here is a useful ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025632/how-do-i-declare-create-and-use-method-pointers-in-swift/48213241#48213241

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple has made function pointers available as of beta 3, however they can only be referenced not called.

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_16)

> #### Function Pointers
>
> C function pointers are imported into Swift as `CFunctionPointer<Type>`, where `Type` is a
>   Swift function type. For example, a function pointer that has the type `int (*)(void)` in C 
>   is imported into Swift as `CFunctionPointer<() -> Int32>`

[Beta 3 Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_3_lpw27r/xcode_6_beta_3_release_notes__.pdf) (PDF)

> Function pointers are also imported now, and can be referenced and passed around. However,
>   you cannot call a C function pointer or convert a closure to C function pointer type.

Answer (score 18):

**This answer refers to an earlier version of the Swift language and may no longer be reliable.**

While C function pointers are *not* available in Swift, you can still use swift closures which are passed to C functions as blocks.

Doing so requires a few "shim" routines in C to take the block and wrap it in a C function.  The following demonstrates how it works.

Swift:

```
func foo(myInt: CInt) -> CInt {
    return myInt
}

var closure: (CInt) -> CInt = foo;

my_c_function(closure)
```

C:

```
void my_c_function(int (^closure)(int))
{
    int x = closure(10);
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
}
```

Of course what you choose to do with the closure, and how you store and recall it for use is up to you.  But this should give you a start.

Comment: So is there a straightforward way to convert the closure into a function pointer from C code? Like say I have some intermediate C code that accepts a closure as one of it's arguments, and I want to call the original lua function that accepts a function pointer. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do.  Off hand, it would be dangerous to try to convert the closure pointer to a function without knowing the particulars of how its implemented...  If it's just one or two closures you're going to pass, you can create a C shim that saves the closure as a pointer, and C function that (that you pass into lua) that calls that closure.  There are many ways to skin this cat.  Sorry I can't help you any further.

Comment: No that's extremely helpful, thank you. I'm going to mark this as the correct answer since I think it's about as close to a solution as we're going to get right now. I'm going to cross my fingers that Swift gains support for function pointers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13) it is noted that `C function pointers are not imported in Swift`.

Comment: `C function pointers are imported into Swift as closures with the C function pointer calling convention, denoted by the @convention(c) attribute. For example, a function pointer that has the type int (*)(void) in C is imported into Swift as @convention(c) () -> Int32.

If the type of the value pointed to by a C pointer cannot be represented by Swift, as is the case with an incomplete struct type, the pointer is imported as an OpaquePointer.`

Answer (score 2):

Since **Swift 3.1** an arbitrary address being a function pointer can be called like this:

```
let fakeIMP = unsafeBitCast(0x1e233d1d0, to: IMP.self)
unsafeBitCast(fakeIMP,to:(@convention(c)()->Void).self)()
```

Assuming for this^ particular call signature:

```
void cFunction();
```

Comment: Accessing the parameters (inside of  an objective c function which I have obtained the pointer of and using your technique have called in swift) causes a memory crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). How can I pass parameters in and use them?

Comment: Using `@convention(c)`, check my answer here for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714950/5329717

Comment: My function pointer points to a global Objective-C function, rather than a method. Does that change things?

Comment: @Div There are no functions in pure objective C. Objective-C methods are always defined in class scope either as class instance method or class static method. Perhaps you meant a C function with arguments. It would be easier to address your case if you create your own question with all the details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108482/bidirectional-data-exchange-between-macos-bundles-swift thanks