# How to pass C++ callback function as variable into C++ function in a Swift code

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

I'd like to call a C++ function, and the function has another function as callback function.

While in Objective-C, this is how I do:

```
cpp.h

typedef void (* FRAME_CALLBACK) (unsigned long, unsigned char *, unsigned long, long, long , VIDEO_B2_FRAME *);

Handle MOpen( void );

void MSetFrameCallback( Handle h, unsigned long param, FRAME_CALLBACK fnCallback );
```

and then in the Objective-C code:

```
objc.m

Hnadle handle = MOpen();

MSetFrameCallback(handle, (id)self, frameCallback);


void frameCallback(id param, unsigned char *rawData, unsigned long dataLen, long width, long height, VIDEO_B2_FRAME *b2)
{
    ViewController *VC = (ViewController *)param;
    [VC updateFrameWithData:rawData dataLen:dataLen width:width height:height];
}
```

But how should I do when this thing in the Swift code?
I can't figure it out.

I know if I want to use ObjC or C++ Class or function that I should create a bridging file.
In that situation, it works fine, but the scenario above I have no idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Swift not work with function pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088312/does-swift-not-work-with-function-pointers)