# Working with C APIs from Swift

Tags: ios, c, swift, utf-8, callback

I'm trying to keep track of the network status. I went through the code of the [FXReachability](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXReachability). Specifically the following method.

```
- (void)setHost:(NSString *)host
{
    if (host != _host)
    {
        if (_reachability)
        {
            SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop(_reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
            CFRelease(_reachability);
        }
        _host = [host copy];
        _status = FXReachabilityStatusUnknown;
        _reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, [_host UTF8String]);
        SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = { 0, ( __bridge void *)self, NULL, NULL, NULL };
        SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(_reachability, ONEReachabilityCallback, &context);
        SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(_reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    }
}
```

What it does is it keeps checking the connection to the specified host. I'm trying to convert this method to Swift and I'm having a couple of problems.

**1. Converting the host string to UTF8.**

I have to convert the host string to UTF8 and pass it into the [SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName) method. I can't find the exact Swift equivalent of `UTF8String` property in Objective-C. But there is a property called `utf8` for the `String` type. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html),

> You can access a UTF-8 representation of a String by iterating over its utf8 property. This property is of type String.UTF8View, which is a collection of unsigned 8-bit (UInt8) values, one for each byte in the string’s UTF-8 representation:

How can I get a complete UTF8 representation of a string instead of a collection of unsigned 8-bit (UInt8) values?

---

**2. Callback function for [SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback).**

Th second parameter of this function expects something of type `SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack`. I dived in to the source file and found out that it's actually a `typealias`.

```
typealias SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack = CFunctionPointer<((SCNetworkReachability!, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void)>
```

I defined it like this.

```
let reachabilityCallBack: SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack = {

}()
```

But I get the error *Missing return in a closure expected to return 'SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack'* when in that typealias you can clearly see that it returns `Void`.

Is this the wrong way to do this?

---

These are the problems I'm facing. I've been at this for hours now with no luck so I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first problem can be solved with

```
let reachability = host.withCString {
    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, $0).takeRetainedValue()
}
```

Inside the closure, `$0` is a pointer to the NUL-terminated UTF-8 representation of the
String.

**Update:** As [Nate Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59541/nate-cook) said in
a now deleted answer and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27065501/1187415),
you can actually pass a Swift string to a function taking a `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`
directly:

```
let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host).takeRetainedValue()
```

---

Unfortunately there is (as far as I know) currently no solution to your second problem.
`SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback` expects a pointer to a C function as second
parameter, and there is currently no method to pass a Swift function or closure.
Note that the documentation for [`SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack)
shows only Objective-C but no Swift.

See also [Does Swift not work with function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088312/does-swift-not-work-with-function-pointers).

---

**Update for Swift 2:** It is now possible to pass a Swift closure
to a C function taking a function pointer parameter. Also
`SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName()` 
does not return an unmanaged object anymore:

```
let host = "google.com"
var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!

SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, _) in
    print(flags)
}, &context) 

SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
```

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8):**

```
let host = "google.com"
var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!

SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, _) in
    print(flags)
    }, &context)

SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(),
                                         CFRunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Limitations suck :( One small thing. Now the type of reachability is `Unmanaged<SCNetworkReachability>!`. I get the error **'Unmanaged<SCNetworkReachability>' is not identical to 'SCNetworkReachability'** when passing it to other functions. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @Isuru: I forgot the takeRetainedValue(). Should be OK now.

Comment: In the Swift 3 code, what return or output tells you that the app was or wasn't able to contact the specified host?

Comment: @ConfusionTowers: That is not what the Reachability API is about. Compare https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachability-g7d: *"A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device. Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be received by the host."* – Only if you create a TCP connection you'll see if the host/port exists and can be contacted.