# Reachability returning no connection when app re-enters foreground

Tags: swift, networking, reachability

When my application re-enters the foreground, my `SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack` is called with an empty flags object (i.e. without the `reachable` flag) which tells me that the device can no longer reach the asset required...

At first I thought this could simply be because the app entered the background and at that point perhaps a non-reachable notification was sent which is delivered when the app enters the foreground, but there is no subsequent `reachable` callback to the function so this can't be the case.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue, or have any ideas why it might be happening? I'm using the reachability class to show UI, so this is quite key to my application!

Code to setup queue is:

```
// Creates a context
var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
// Sets `self` as listener object
context.info = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged<Reachability>.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

let callbackClosure: SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack? = {

    (reachability:SCNetworkReachability, flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) in

    guard let info = info else { return }
    // Gets the `Handler` object from the context info
    let handler = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()

    handler.queue.async {
        handler.checkReachability(flags: flags)
    }
}
// Registers the callback. `callbackClosure` is the closure where we manage the callback implementation
if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, callbackClosure, &context) {
    // Not able to set the callback
}
```

`SCNetworkReachability` object is setup in the init method:

```
init?(hostName: String) {

    guard let _reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, hostName) else { return nil }

    reachability = _reachability
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300132/5868066 try this

Comment: Did you ever find the reason / solution to this @simonthumper?

Comment: I don't believe I did I'm afraid. I'm fairly certain I just worked around it by observing application state changes.