# Notification in Swift when network is back up after being down

Tags: ios, swift, macos, network-programming

I'd like to have a Swift function called by OS X or iOS when the network connection is back up after being down. For instance, when airplane mode has been disabled. My app should be aware of this instantly and restart using the network right away.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398664/check-for-internet-connection-availability-in-swift#25774420), but it would involve polling, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: You can register a callback function which is called when the reachability status changes, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object or http://stackoverflow.com/a/27142665/1187415.

Comment: user1941284: Working flawlessly with low energy consumption and clean code... Add this as an answer and I confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift to resolve that issue.