# Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

In Swift 2 I was able to write this statement:

```
var reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "www.apple.com").takeRetainedValue()
```

In Swift 3 now it says that SCNetworkReachability? has no member  takeRetainedValue().

Comment: Could it be that `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName` is now correctly converted in Swift3? I that case just drop the `takeRetainedValue()`.

Comment: `takeRetainedValue()` is not needed here since Swift 2, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142263/working-with-c-apis-from-swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the takeRetainedValue() you don't need it anymore.

```
var reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "www.apple.com")
```