# How do I declare, create, and use method pointers in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures, pointer-to-member

I'm not talking about pointers to C functions, but to a method within a Swift type.

```
struct Test: GeneratorType {
    var methodPointer: mutating () -> Bool?  // Non-working guess
    var which: Bool

    init() {
        which = false
        methodPointer = which ? &testMethod1 : &testMethod2  // Also non-working guess
    }

    //...
}
```

The compiler says "`mutating`" isn't legal as part of a function declaration. (Actually, it just suggests a semi-colon there.)  And for the pointer initialization (after I remove `mutating`), the compiler thinks I'm trying to call the functions and use their results instead.  I want to use the methods as objects in-and-of themselves here, not as a function call.  Later on I want to use the pointed-to method within `next`; without figuring this out, I'll have to resort to an enumeration flag and manually choosing which method to call within `next`.

I hope there's some part of closure mechanics that allows this.  Maybe something like [this page, which describes functions returning functions](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/). But none of the examples I've seen mention `mutating` methods.

Comment: The link you provided was from July 2014 and should not be trusted. That was a month after Swift came out and those articles tend to be misleading, incorrect and obsolete.
You can try Swift docs on closures. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: From looking at [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/JadenGeller/status/619426292232908800), I don't think `mutating` methods are supported, even if I can figure out how to call non-`static` methods.

Comment: My attempts frequently end at "Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed".

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you.

```
class Something {
    var f: ( () -> Int )?
    let f1 = { () -> Int in /* do some action here */ return 1}
    let f2 = { () -> Int in /* do some action here */ return 2}

    func ff(which: Bool) {
        f = which ? f1 : f2
    }

    func act() {
        if let f = f {
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it. It works, but I could *not* access `self` or any properties from `f1` or `f2`, so it's useless to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it -

```
class FcnArgs {                             //@goal  pass a fcn as arg

    class func demo() {
        let fPtr = funcToPointTo;           //@type  '((Int)->String)'
        print(fPtr(4));
    }

    class func funcToPointTo(_ i : Int) -> String {
        print("I Was passed \(i)"); 
        return "I was returned";
    }
}
```

FcnArgs.demo() output:

```
I Was passed 4
I was returned
```