# How to initialize and use function pointer in Swift

Tags: swift, function-pointers

**Let's say I have this code snipped in the playground**

```
import UIKit

internal final class TestClass {
    internal final var funcPointer: () -> Void

    init() {
        self.funcPointer = self.func1() //Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '() -> Void'
    }

    internal final func func1() {
        print("func1 is called!")
    }
}

var testClass: TestClass = TestClass()
testClass.funcPointer()
```

Why do I get the shown error message within the init() method and how to initialize a function pointer correctly?

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025632/how-do-i-declare-create-and-use-method-pointers-in-swift) SO post and [this](https://medium.com/swift-programming/facets-of-swift-part-4-functions-3cce9d9bba4) tutorial but anyway I don't get it to work for a (Void) -> Void function...

Comment: Did you notice that the answers in the post you linked don't call the function when assigning it to a variable? That was intentional.

Comment: Nit pick: that's not a function pointer, it's a closure. Closures happen to be implemented using function pointers, although even that's not always the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign the **closure** to the property you have to remove the parentheses

```
self.funcPointer = self.func1
```

The subsequent error

> self' used in method call 'func1' before all stored properties are initialized

can be fixed by declaring `funcPointer` implicit unwrapped optional

```
internal final var funcPointer: (() -> Void)!
```

Comment: Could you also answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348309/avoid-retain-cycles-for-function-pointers-in-swift-5 :)